# Where to store access token and how to keep track of user (using JWT token in Http only cookie)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, cookies, jwt

Trying to understand how to get and then save user in client (using JWT token in Http only cookie), so that I can do conditional rendering. What I'm having difficulty with is how to continously know if the user is logged in or not, without having to send a request to the server each time the user changes/refresh page. (Note: the problem is not how do I get the token in the Http only cookie, I know that this is done through `withCredentials: true`)

So my problem is how do you get/store the access token so that the client will not have to make a request to the server each time the user does something on the website. For example the Navbar should do conditional renderingen depending on if the user is logged in or not, then I don't want to do "ask the server if the user has a access token, then if not check if user has refresh token, then return a new access token if true else redirect to login page" every single time the user switches page.

Client:

UserContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";
export const UserContext = createContext(null);
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  const [context, setContext] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ context, setContext }}>
          <Navbar />
          <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
          <Route path="/sign-in" exact component={SignIn} />
          <Route path="/sign-up" exact component={SignUp} />
          <Route path="/profile" exact component={Profile} />
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Profile.js

```
import { GetUser } from "../api/AuthenticateUser";

const Profile = () => {
  const { context, setContext } = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {context}
      <button onClick={() => GetUser()}>Change context</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

AuthenticateUser.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export const GetUser = () => {
  try {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/get-user", {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Axios request failed: ${e}`);
  }
};
```

Server:

AuthenticateUser.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
// hashing algorithm
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const salt = 10;

// app objects instantiated on creation of the express server
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "mysql_db",
});

//create access token
const createAccessToken = (user) => {
  // create new JWT access token
  const accessToken = jwt.sign(
    { id: user.id, email: user.email },
    process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
    {
      expiresIn: "1h",
    }
  );
  return accessToken;
};

//create refresh token
const createRefreshToken = (user) => {
  // create new JWT access token
  const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
    { id: user.id, email: user.email },
    process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
    {
      expiresIn: "1m",
    }
  );
  return refreshToken;
};

// verify if user has a valid token, when user wants to access resources
const authenticateAccessToken = (req, res, next) => {
  //check if user has access token
  const accessToken = req.cookies["access-token"];

  // if access token does not exist
  if (!accessToken) {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }

  // check if access token is valid
  // use verify function to check if token is valid
  jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
    req.user = user;
    return next();
  });
};

app.post("/token", (req, res) => {
  const refreshToken = req.cookies["refresh-token"];
  // check if refresh token exist
  if (!refreshToken) return res.sendStatus(401);

  // verify refresh token
  jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(401);

    // check for refresh token in database and identify potential user
    sqlFindUser = "SELECT * FROM user_db WHERE refresh_token = ?";
    db.query(sqlFindUser, [refreshToken], (err, user) => {
      // if no user found
      if (user.length === 0) return res.sendStatus(401);

      const accessToken = createAccessToken(user[0]);
      res.cookie("access-token", accessToken, {
        maxAge: 10000*60, //1h
        httpOnly: true, 
      });
      res.send(user[0]);
    });
  });
});

/**
 * Log out functionality which deletes all cookies containing tokens and deletes refresh token from database
 */
app.delete("/logout", (req, res) => {
  const refreshToken = req.cookies["refresh-token"];
  // delete refresh token from database
  const sqlRemoveRefreshToken =
    "UPDATE user_db SET refresh_token = NULL WHERE refresh_token = ?";
  db.query(sqlRemoveRefreshToken, [refreshToken], (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(401);

    // delete all cookies
    res.clearCookie("access-token");
    res.clearCookie("refresh-token");
    res.end();
  });
});

// handle user sign up
app.post("/sign-up", (req, res) => {
  //request information from frontend
  const { first_name, last_name, email, password } = req.body;

  // hash using bcrypt
  bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send({ err: err });
    }

    // insert into backend with hashed password
    const sqlInsert =
      "INSERT INTO user_db (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    db.query(sqlInsert, [first_name, last_name, email, hash], (err, result) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
  });
});

/*
 * Handel user login
 */
app.post("/sign-in", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  sqlSelectAllUsers = "SELECT * FROM user_db WHERE email = ?";
  db.query(sqlSelectAllUsers, [email], (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send({ err: err });
    }

    if (user && user.length > 0) {
      // given the email check if the password is correct

      bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].password, (err, compareUser) => {
        if (compareUser) {
          //req.session.email = user;
          // create access token
          const accessToken = createAccessToken(user[0]);
          const refreshToken = createRefreshToken(user[0]);
          // create cookie and store it in users browser
          res.cookie("access-token", accessToken, {
            maxAge: 10000*60, //1h
            httpOnly: true, 
          });
          res.cookie("refresh-token", refreshToken, {
            maxAge: 2.63e9, // approx 1 month
            httpOnly: true,
          });

          // update refresh token in database
          const sqlUpdateToken =
            "UPDATE user_db SET refresh_token = ? WHERE email = ?";
          db.query(
            sqlUpdateToken,
            [refreshToken, user[0].email],
            (err, result) => {
              if (err) {
                res.send(err);
              }
              res.sendStatus(200);
            }
          );
        } else {
          res.send({ message: "Wrong email or password" });
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.send({ message: "Wrong email or password" });
    }
  });
});

app.get("/get-user", (req, res) => {
  const accessToken = req.cookies["acceess-token"];
  const refreshToken = req.cookies["refresh-token"];
  //if (!accessToken && !refreshToken) res.sendStatus(401);

  // get user from database using refresh token
  // check for refresh token in database and identify potential user
  sqlFindUser = "SELECT * FROM user_db WHERE refresh_token = ?";
  db.query(sqlFindUser, [refreshToken], (err, user) => {
    console.log(user);
    return res.json(user);
  });
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("running on port 4000");
});
```

I began experimenting with useContext as you can see in the client code above. My initial idea was to use useEffect in the App component where I make a call to the function GetUser() which makes a request to "/get-user" which will user the refreshToken to find the user (don't know if it is bad practice to use refreshToken to find user in db, maybe I should store access token in db as well and use it to find user in db instead?) and then save things like id, first name, last name and email so that it may be displayed in the navbar or any other component if necessary.

However, I don't know if this is the right thing to do as I have heard a lot about using localStorge, memory or sessionStorage is better for keeping the JWT access token in, while you should keep the refresh token in the server and save it in the mySQL database I have created, only to be used once the user has lost their access token. How should I get access to my access token and how do I keep track of the user logged in? Do I really need to do a request to the server each time the user switches page or refresh page?

Also I have a question about when I should be calling "/token" in the server to create new access tokens. Should I always try to use the access token to do things that require authentication and if it for example returns `null` at some point then I make request to "/token" and after that repeat what the user was trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I really need to do a request to the server each time the user switches page or refresh page?

That is the safest way. If you want to keep with the current security best practices for SPAs, then using http-only, secure, same-site cookies is the best option. Refreshes won't happen that often on your page, so it shouldn't be a problem.

> My initial idea was to use useEffect in the App component where I make a call to the function GetUser() which makes a request to "/get-user" which will user the refreshToken to find the user

What I would do is to first verify the access token, if it's valid then take the userId out of the access token (if you don't have it there you can easily add it as you're creating the tokens manually) and read the user data from the database. If the access token is invalid then return an error to the website and let the user use the refresh token to get a new access token. So I wouldn't mix responsibilities here - I wouldn't use refresh token to get information about the logged in user.

> Also I have a question about when I should be calling "/token" in the server to create new access tokens. Should I always try to use the access token to do things that require authentication and if it for example returns null at some point then I make request to "/token" and after that repeat what the user was trying to do?

Yes, that's how it usually is implemented. You make a call with the access token to a protected endpoint. It would be best if the endpoint returned 401 response if the token is expired or invalid. Then your app knows that it should use the refresh token to get a new access token. Once you have a new access token you try to make the call to the protected endpoint again. If you don't manage to get a new access token (e.g. because the refresh token has expired), then you ask the user to log in again.